# Can you FieldValue.increment a Firestore map value?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Given a field 'count' which has the following value...

```
{
  "0": 5,
  "1": 3,
  "2": 2,
  "3": 1,
  "4": 4
}
```

Is it possible to increment each of these values?

I attempted to update with the following but it does not increment, just sets the values to the increment value.

```
let delta = new Object();
delta["0"] = FieldValue.increment(5);
...
doc.ref.update({ "count": delta });
```

whereas I would have expected the following incremented data...

```
{
  "0": 10,
  "1": 3,
  "2": 2,
  "3": 1,
  "4": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given something like...

```
let delta = new Object();
for (int i = 0; i < len(other); i++) {
  delta[i.toString()] = FieldValue.increment(i*2);
}
...
doc.ref.update({ "count": delta });
```

`FieldValue.increment` does not appear to be able to be embedded as a value within Lists or nested Maps. Firestore only looks at the top-level object and replaces the rest below wholesale - that would explain why increments fail in this case.

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects#node.js_11 :

"Dot notation allows you to update a single nested field without overwriting other nested field. If you update a nested field without dot notation, you will overwrite the entire map field"

For `update()` operations, directly reference the composite field name + key name (i.e. `"count.x"`) via dot notation. Something like...

```
let delta = {};
let other = [0, 2, 6, 7];
for (int i = 0; i < other.length; i++) {
  let key = other[i];
  let fieldName = "count." + key.toString();
  delta[fieldName] = FieldValue.increment(key * 2);
}
...
doc.ref.update(delta);
```

However, for `set()` operations, passing this same `delta` fails. Firestore defaults to interpreting the fieldName `"count.x": val` as a unique field, rather than the desired nested `"count": { "x": val }`.

Dot notation overloads the meaning of '.' in a field name, so this may be a bug that will be resolved down the line, but it's not very deterministic. At least for now, different logic is needed to initialize `count`. It could be as simple as something like...

```
docRef = db.collection(collectionName).doc();
await docRef.set({ "count": { "0": 0 }});
```

followed by the `update()` above.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that field value you showed is not actually just a single map value.  It's actually 5 field values, with each nested map value being its own field.  If that map were stored in a field called `count`, there would be 5 indexed fields known as `count.0`, `count.1`, `count.2`, `count.3`, and `count.4`.  (Learn more about [dot notation for fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).)

Given that this is actually 5 individual fields, and if you wanted to increment them each, that would require 5 different field updates, each with its own value incremented.

```
doc.ref.update({
  "count.0": FieldValue.increment(5),
  "count.1": FieldValue.increment(5),
  "count.2": FieldValue.increment(5),
  "count.3": FieldValue.increment(5),
  "count.4": FieldValue.increment(5),
});
```

Note that array field values cannot be targeted by dot notation like this.  It only applies to nested map type fields.

Comment: On the first point, I kept it to one of the 5 being updated for brevity; in reality I am updating all of them. Sorry, I guess that made it more confusing. I'm going to give the dot notation a stab though and see if that works as I expected. Hoping this count key can be enumerated programmatically though, as hard-coding "count.4" is not viable; the number of map keys is flexible.

Comment: There are no options to update multiple values with one line of code.  Your only option is dot notation on each of the individual field values.

Comment: It can be as many lines of code as necessary. I cannot hard-code 5 `{ "count.x": y }` lines so I am currently attempting to compose an object with `"count.x"`, `"count.x+1"`, ..., `"count.max(x)"` to pass into `update()`. Hopefully you're not saying that's also impossible.

Comment: I find using comments very difficult for adding clarification, so I updated my original question to add the fact that the # keys is variable (and clarify the other points of ambiguity you raised in your answer). I hope this is much more clear than my comment attempts :)

Comment: I updated to clarify the conditions of the question, not updating it to incorporate your answer.

Comment: Okay, you have made assumptions about unstated parts of the question so that it's the one you want to answer? That seems like much poorer form. I'm going to give up on trying to clarify for you as you seem to want to be argumentative and pedantic instead of productive.

Comment: In your update, it looks like you attempted to use a loop to build the update object to perform a set of increments on nested fields.  That's a different problem than the one you started with, which is solved by using Firestore dot notation to call out the individual named nested fields that you originally showed.  If you ask that as a separate question, it will certainly get a customized answer to address the new code and document data you show.